# Cannot access hidden files on Nexus 5 after root

Tags: nexus-5, usb-debugging, usb-drivers, file-management, file-permissions

I'm making some apps for android and wanted to **change files in the data/data/com.myapp/** folder, so I decided to root my Nexus 5.

This did the opposite of what I wanted. I **used to be able to VIEW hidden files**, but not modify them. Now, **after root I cannot see anything but default folders** (DCIM, Download, Music...) on my phone in windows explorer.

- Windows explorer file options is set to see all files
- I think this may be a USB driver issue, but have tried all the drivers in the sdk folder
- I do not want to use ADB commands to manage files, i do not think this is necessary

I'd be grateful for any help with this. I've looked at other posts and forums and cannot find anything similar to this.

Comment: Is your phone in MTP, PTP, or Mass Storage mode?  Is USB Debugging enabled?  Try various combinations of those.

Comment: I did. It looks like this has been a bug in android since 2012. The one other thread I managed to find basically said it was a stroke of luck that I could see those files in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used ADB to give myself access to data/data/my.app.dir as well as the folders and files therein, then to pull them to my computer.

For some reason I could not pull files directly from their location (even with the ABD shell closed), so copied them to a the phone's emulated storage and pull them from there.

I wrote a simple batch script to easily pull the files I wanted:

```
@echo off
echo Database transfer progress:
adb shell su -c "chmod 777 /data"
adb shell su -c "chmod 777 /data/data"
adb shell su -c "chmod 777 /data/data/my.app.dir"
adb shell su -c "chmod 777 /data/data/my.app.dir/databases"
adb shell su -c "chmod 777 /data/data/my.app.dir/databases/MyDatabase"
adb shell su -c "cp /data/data/my.app.dir/databases/MyDatabase /sdcard/Download"
adb pull /sdcard/Download/MyDatabase C:\Temp
adb shell su -c "rm /sdcard/Download/MyDatabase"
echo[
REM - pause and check for errors
pause
```

I don't care about reverting permissions on this device, but rebooting the phone seems to reset them.